# In Genesis 22:14, which is more accurate Jehova Jireh or Adonai Yireh? Are they the same or different? Is it “God will provide”, or “God will be seen

Tags: hebrew, translation, genesis-bereishith

Genesis 22:14, Abraham calls the place Jehova Jireh, which I always understood as “God will provide”. But is it really “Adonai Yireh which your site has “On God's mountain he will be seen”. Which is more accurate according to the original meaning?

Comment: The question is a good one, though the title is misleading - the verse uses the Tetragrammaton and is read using Adonai, as per Jewish law.

Comment: The title is somewhat misleading, as the body of the question asks a different question. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Rashi, a classical commentator, [explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.22.14?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.22.14.1&lang2=bi), based on the Aramaic meaning that: "'ה יראה Its real meaning is as the Targum renders it: The Lord will choose and select for Himself this place to make His Shechinah reside in it and for sacrifices to be offered there."

Comment: The two phrases of Hebrew you're using are clouding your question over the meaning. The phrases are the same. The difference is where they come from. "Jehova Jireh" is a Latinized form of "Adonai Yireh." Christians made the "J" sound and changed the vowels to come up with "Jehova." I know it was very popular in Christianity, but it's just a made-up word. Your question seems focused on the 'yireh' part. The other is just in the way.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that the translation you knew is a classic Christian translation, which seems to deduce that the meaning of "yir'eh" in this context is "will provide" based on verse 8 "וַיֹּאמֶר אַבְרָהָם **אֱלֹהִים יִרְאֶה לּוֹ הַשֶּׂה לְעֹלָה** בְּנִי וַיֵּלְכוּ שְׁנֵיהֶם יַחְדָּו." which literally should be translated as "Abraham said: **God will show him the sacrificial lamb**, my son, and they walked together." However, in context the word "show" seems to imply "provide". Thus, in the later verse 14, the word "yir'eh" is also translated in Christian bibles as "provide". However, it still very much literally means "show" or "see" or "seen". Jewish translations tend to prefer translating the Hebrew as literally as possible.

So the answer to your question is that it depends on what do you mean by the original meaning. If you mean the literal meaning, then you would go with show/see/seen. If you mean the contextual meaning, then provide certainly makes sense in verse 8, but in verse 14 it might be more debatable, given that in the end, an angel of God did show himself to Abraham (verse 11).